# Embbeding JW player 5.1 on facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, jwplayer

I'm making a web of videos and i need to put these in the facebook wall of my users when they push the share button. I'm using JW player 5.1 and I read this tutorial http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/19150/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player/ following all the steps. I think that my code is correctly and the facebook debugger told me that is correct.

Here is a example link of my web that I would like to share http://www.youshow.com.es/prueba.php .

Please, can someone help me?

Thanks.

P.S: I think that is because I don't have a SSL certificate and in the tutorial mentioned talks about the https limitations.

Comment: To add to the notes below, not only do you need https, but Facebook has changed something recently as well that has broken this method, we are investigating this here as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try viewing Facebook over HTTP instead of HTTPS. One thing I noticed is you are missing the open graph namespace in your html-tag. So change

```
<html>
```

to

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment from the tutorial you linked to:

```
For those struggling, recently FB made it required to have the video:secure_url in order to have videos properly embed.
This means you need to have your player be on HTTPS - SSL.
```